# How to make a collection_select disabled in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wan't to disable a collection_select and already tested the followings code:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:categoria_id, Categoria.order(:descricao), :id, :descricao,{ class: "form-control", :disabled => "disabled" }) %>
<%= f.collection_select(:categoria_id, Categoria.order(:descricao), :id, :descricao,{ class: "form-control", :disabled => true }) %>
<%= f.collection_select(:categoria_id, Categoria.order(:descricao), :id, :descricao, class: "form-control", :disabled => "disabled") %>
<%= f.collection_select(:categoria_id, Categoria.order(:descricao), :id, :descricao, class: "form-control", :disabled => true) %>
```

None of them work, anyone know why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From rails documentation

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}) public
```

Note there is a option attribute before the html options attribute. If you are not defining any options then you have to include a empty braces before defining any html options.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:categoria_id, Categoria.order(:descricao), :id, :descricao,{},{ class: "form-control", :disabled => "disabled" }) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm... but one thing that I didn't get it, is that the `class: "form-control"` worked in the option attribute and in the html attribute...

Comment: Note, `disabled: true` also works.